# Vaadin 23 TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

In Firefox browser, not always (but very often) I see the following error in the console (and page is unable to load):

```
TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module
```

Only after Ctrl + F5 the page is loaded correctly.

Also in the Network tab I may see the following:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module router.js:525:10
    ready router.js:525
    (Async: promise callback)
    render router.js:517
    __onNavigationEvent router.js:932
    setRoutes router.js:419
    index.ts:32
```

There is no any other information. In Chrome, everything works fine. What may be the reason of this issue?

I noticed this after upgrade to Vaadin 23.2.1
Also, from time to time I have the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you check this ticket in Vaadin's issue tracker: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14534

Comment: Sure, but looks like you already added it there.